# Can't get jackson jsr 310 to work on weblogic 12.2.1

Tags: java, spring, weblogic

I can't get weblogic to handle java 8 LocalDate. I'm deploying a spring boot project to weblogic and everything else works fine.

My current configuration for java time module works if I start the application as a spring boot application on a tomcat embedded server, but not when I deploy to weblogic.

This is what I have tried so far:

*weblogic.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app>
    <weblogic-version>12.2.1</weblogic-version>
    <context-root>/</context-root>
    <container-descriptor>
        <prefer-application-packages>
            <package-name>org.slf4j.*</package-name>
            <package-name>org.apache.commons.*</package-name>
            <package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.*</package-name>
            <package-name>org.codehaus.jackson.*</package-name>
        </prefer-application-packages>

        <prefer-application-resources>
            <resource-name>org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class</resource-name>
        </prefer-application-resources>
    </container-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

*Jersey configuration*

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonBuilder() {
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    builder.featuresToDisable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
    return builder;
}
```

Another *Jersey configuration* that I tried:

```
@Configuration
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyConfig() throws JsonProcessingException {
        register(JacksonFeature.class);
        register(JacksonMapperProvider.class);
        packages("my.path");
    }


    public static class JacksonMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {
        @Override
        public ObjectMapper getContext(final Class<?> aClass) {
            final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
            objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
            return objectMapper;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Expected result from the following endpoint (and the output i get when i run it with tomcat)

```
@GET
@Path("test")
public LocalDate test() {
    return LocalDate.ofEpochDay(0);
}
```

is:

```
"1970-01-01"
```

on weblogic i get:

```
{"year":1970,"month":"JANUARY","monthValue":1,"dayOfMonth":1,"dayOfWeek":"THURSDAY","era":"CE","dayOfYear":1,"leapYear":false,"chronology":{"id":"ISO","calendarType":"iso8601"}}
```